# How do I get a textbox with particular ValidationGroup in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery

I have an ASP.NET TextBox ID="txtDate" in my usercontrol. It has ValidationGroup="MyUC" set. Now my UC is inside a Repeater Control. So there will be multiple instances of the same textbox. 
I am able to get all textboxes like: `$("[id$='_txtDate']");`

Each of the txtDate will have a separate ValidationGroup assigned to it, dynamically.
So I want to get a textbox based on the id + ValidationGroup using jQuery / javascript.

How can it be done? Any guidance really appreciated.

Edited based on Josiah's Reply and the way I found:

Sorry, my scenario is kind of complicated to include entire code. In short the textboxes are attached to jquery datepicker and the code below runs when a date is selected. The same handler is attached to multiple textboxes. Here is what I have:

```
var valgrp="MyGroup"; /*this mygroup is dynamic but keeping static for e.g.*/ 
var txtdate1 = $("[id$='txtDate']").filter(function(){if(this.Validators!=null){return this.Validators[0].validationGroup == valgrp;}});
var txtdate2 = $("[id$='txtDate']").filter(function(){return this.validationGroup == valgrp;});
alert("date1- " + txtdate1.val()); /*this returns date selected from datepicker*/
alert("date2 " + txtdate2.val()); /*this returns empty*/
```

Depending on the date I want to do something else. So txtdate1 is currently working for me where I don't have to add class to my textbox. I was playing with the txtdate2 which isn't behaving how I was expecting and so I had to post this question.

Here is a sample test to see this.validationGroup not returned:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#btntest").click(function () {
                $("[id$='txtDate']").each(function () {
                    alert(this.validationGroup);//returns undefined
                    alert(this.Validators[0].validationGroup); //returns "test"
                });
            });
        });
  <input id="btntest" type="button" value="button" />
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="test"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Required." ControlToValidate="txtDate" ValidationGroup="test"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Here is someone else's solution http://htmlcoderhelper.com/jquery-validation-multiple-submit-buttons-on-one-asp-net-form-different-validation-groups/

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell: The workaround suggested in there should work i.e. I will have to set CssClass="MyValidationGroup" for my textboxes but I am wondering if there is any other better way. I would prefer doing it in js code only rather than in code-behind. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I believe this would require looking through the javascript validation array that is on the page. I do not have a working asp.net web forms demo running to provide a better solution right now however.

Comment: @Josiah Ruddell: I am pretty positive the setting CssClass is going to work. FYI: I am using asp.net validators and not jquery validate, in case if there is any confusion.

Comment: Right. The asp.net validators output all of the validation fields into an array called `Page_Validators` I believe this array will contain the name of the validation group for each field. A solution would be to enumerate this array on page load and add css validation groups to your fields.

Comment: I posted a possible solution - let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Josiah's solution didn't work but his idea of attaching class to textbox could have been a potential solution. Since it didn't exactly fit my needs I would answer my own question. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
var valgrp="MyGroup"; /*this mygroup is dynamic but keeping static for e.g.*/ 
var txtdate1 = $("[id$='txtDate']").filter(function(){if(this.Validators!=null){return this.Validators[0].validationGroup == valgrp;}});
```

The above returns me the textbox I am looking for. The key is

> this.Validators[0].validationGroup

It gets the validationGroup of the first validator control attached to the textbox (this).

Comment: Ok, its 5 years on, but the issue just cropped up for me. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

From a few searches, the validation group is stored as a property on the Form Element.

So you can add a class selector like so:

```
$("[id$='_txtDate']").each(function(){
    var group = this.validationGroup,
        $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('validationgroup'))
        $this.addClass('validationgroup ' + group);
});
```

Of course if you have a repeater you will need to run this code each time an row is repeated. But now you can select fields by validation group like this:

```
$('.validationgroup.[group name]')
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this.validationGroup earlier and somehow it is behaving weired. I did found another way to do it. I get the Validators expando properites and get the validationgroup from the validator attached to that textbox. I am going to update my question with what I have got.

Comment: Actually this.validationGroup won't work because the reason it was giving me empty text for txtdate2 was it was filtering one of my validator control that was ending in txtDate. The text for it is empty and so I got txtdate2="". When I replaced my selection like this: var txtdate2 = $("input[id$='txtDate']").filter(function(){return this.validationGroup == valgrp;}); I started getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use jQuery, but I'd think it would be:

```
$("#txtDate[ValidationGroup='MyUc']")
```

since jQuery's selectors are based on CSS. That works with document.querySelector, unless having more that one element with the same id is causing problems.

Comment: I do not believe .NET WebForms outputs attributes to DOMElements for their server control attributes. Generally this metadata is stored in an .axd file, or ViewState

Comment: I already tried that earlier and it didn't work. Why? Because ValidationGroup is not rendered into the textbox markup as an attribute by asp.net nor do I see it as an expando property. I am not even sure why that property is exposed for TextBox control.